# Error in linked list implementation of stack

Tags: c

I want to do linked list implementation of stack however my code is not working as expected.
I am not able to discover whats causing the issue hence i will be posting my code, the present output and ideal output.
i could not figure how to add  in if condition that n is alphabet then execute if statement for input like no. 456 or execute else statement.
kindly help if you figure the issue.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node*head;

void push(char x){
    if (head == NULL) {
        head= (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->data=x;
        head->next=NULL;
        printf("additon successful\n");        
        return ;
    }
    struct node *temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->next=head;
    temp->data=x;
    head=temp;
    printf("additon successful\n");  
    return ;
}

void pop(){
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return ;
}
struct node *temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp=head;
head=head->next;
free(temp);
printf("pop is successful\n");
return ;
}

void print(){
    struct node *temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%c  ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nall items printed\n");
    return ;
}
void main() {
    char n;
    printf("enter alphabet\n");
    while (0!=1){
    scanf("%c",&n);
    if(n != 1 && n!= '`' && n!= 4 ) {
    push(n);}
    else if(n == 1) {
    pop();}
    else if(n == '`') {
    print();}
    else if(n == 4) {
    printf("\nexiting program");
    return ;}
    else {
    printf("enter valid argument\n");}
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter alphabet
r
additon successful             // why is this printing twice?
additon successful
a
additon successful
additon successful
n
additon successful
additon successful
d
additon successful
additon successful
1                               // for 1 code should perform pop operation
additon successful
additon successful
4                               // for 4 function should end        
additon successful
additon successful
456                             // i could not figure how to add  in if condition that n is 
                                   aplphabet then execute if statement for such no. like 456 
                                   execute else 
additon successful
additon successful
additon successful              //why so many executions?
additon successful
```

IDEAL OUTPUT:

```
1
list is empty
r
additon successful
e
additon successful
a
additon successful
d
additon successful
1
pop is successful
1
pop is successful
`
a  d
all items printed
456
enter valid argument
4
exiting program
```

Comment: `void main()` isn't very portable. Most implementations expect `main` to return `int`.

Comment: @vatsal The program prints twice the message "additon successful" because it reads the new line character '\n'. Change this call scanf("%c",&n); to scanf(" %c",&n); Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

Comment: When you test your program avoid user input.

Comment: `4` and `'4'` have different values.

Comment: What @IanAbbott said: Did you hardcode `4` because you mean CTRL-D ?

Comment: @ted lungmo i have edited the question and rectified the mistake

Comment: @vlad from moscow how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: @vatsal By reading my comment one more.:)

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow sorry for replying in hassle and your suggestion worked.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow do you have clue why is 1 not performing pop and 4 exiting fom the function?

Comment: The input `456` would be read as a series of 3 values, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`. (There may also be newline value `'\n'` before the `'4'` and after the `'6'` unless you change the `scanf` format string to `" %c"` to discard whitespace characters.)

Comment: @Ian abbott thank for suggestion i changed it and it worked do you have clue why is 1 not performing pop and 4 exiting fom the function?

Comment: You need to change the tests to check for the values `'1'` and `'4'` instead of `1` and `4`. You check each value in more than one place, so you need to change it in all those places.

Comment: @ian abbott thanks the code is working fine now.

Comment: Why do `pop()` and `print()` call `malloc()`?

Comment: @ian abbott yes i removed them they were error

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow thanks the code is working fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>           //added this library to use 'isalpha' a 
                             // function to check wheteher the symbol is 
                             //alphabet or not.


struct node{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node*head;

void push(char x){
    if (head == NULL) {
        head= (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->data=x;
        head->next=NULL;
        printf("additon successful\n");        
        return ;
    }
    struct node *temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->next=head;
    temp->data=x;
    head=temp;
    printf("additon successful\n");  
    return ;
}

void pop(){
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return ;
}
struct node *temp;             //removed malloc since we only need a 
                               //pointer and not a memory block
temp=head;
head=head->next;
free(temp);
printf("pop is successful\n");
return ;
}

void print(){
    struct node *temp;           //removed malloc since we only need 
                                 //a pointer and not a memory block
    temp=head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%c  ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nall items printed\n");
    return ;
}
int main() {                //void main() isn't very portable. Most 
                            //implementations expect main to return int.
    char n;
    printf("enter alphabet\n");
    while (0!=1){
    scanf(" %c",&n);       //the program prints twice the message 
                           //"additon successful" because it reads the 
                           //new line character '\n'. Change this call 
                           //scanf("%c",&n); to scanf(" %c",&n); Pay 
                           //attention to the leading space in the 
                           //format string. It allows to skip white 
                           //space characters.    
    if(isalpha(n)) {                   
    push(n);}
    else if(n == '1') {      //'1' instead of 1
    pop();}
    else if(n == '`') {
    print();}
    else if(n == '4') {      //used' 4' instead of 4
    printf("\nexiting program");
    return 0;}
    else {
    printf("enter valid argument\n");}
    }
}
```

final solution

Comment: Glad you figured it out. One detail about formatting: You will likely have to adapt to something very different from the style you use now when you start collaborating with other people. Perhaps it'd be good to start that adaption already because not many people are used to reading code formatted like in your `if`/`else`s - and you probably want to make your future questions easy to read.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for your suggestion BTW what else should i use to avoid  if / else  conditions?

Comment: You don't have to avoid them. It's just the formatting that hurts :-) A `switch` can also be used in similar situations if you want something else.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what you changed to solve the problem.

Comment: @Barmar ok i changed it as you said

Comment: Now your code is invalid -- comments should be ... in comments. Please also explain outside of the code block, in a normal paragraph of text what you did to solve the problem.

Comment: @trincot i rectified the comments

Comment: *"Please also..."*